# ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection connects to wrong database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created a class which connects to 2 databases:

```
class Production < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)
  self.abstract_class = true
  attr_accessor
end

class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:backup)
  self.abstract_class = true
  attr_accessor
end

class RepairReport
  def init

  end

  def repair_now
    Production.table_name = "users"
    users = Production.all
    users.each do |user|
      puts "USER: #{user.last_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the `database.yml`:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 296
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0

backup:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0
```

When I run this, it gives an error: `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]`

When I change the `database.yml` to `development` and `test` it works, but the outputted users are from another database used in another local Rails application. So it seems an old connection is still active? How can I make sure the right database is connected?

update:

This is now my updated `database.yml` and code (see below), but it still connects to the wrong database. When I remove the `development` and `test` parts, it returns: `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["development_prod", "development_backup"]`, so it seems it is reading the right `database.yml`.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 296
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0

development_prod:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 296
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0

development_backup:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0
```

And code:

```
  class Production < ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_prod".to_sym)
    self.abstract_class = true
    attr_accessor
  end

  class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_backup".to_sym)
    self.abstract_class = true
    attr_accessor
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're running rails app in `development` mode.
By default rails trying to load database config and fetch connection details by `RAILS_ENV` value.

I'd suggest to name connections to both match environment:

```yaml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 296
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0

development_backup:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_eagle_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password1
  template: template0
```

```ruby
class Production < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env)
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_backup")
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: You could try this "#{Rails.env}_backup".to_sym

Comment: I did, but then it still returns data from the wrong database, see my updated question.

Answer (score 5):

It must be `establish_connection(:production)` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)`

The `:establish_connection` method of each specific class must be called, not the parent one which is `ActiveRecord::Base`. Configuring the parent class does not make sense )

Comment: If I could I would both of you give credit, so I had to chose. His solution to use `Rails.env` in the connection helped a lot and he can use some more credits.

Comment: But the problem was not in establishing the right connection based on the environment, but in proper connection configuration! Your code didn't work as you expected, I showed what the problem was. The other answer has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: When you explicitly specify the connection name (as you did) it doesn't matter which environment it is then. So using `Rails.env` didn't solve your problem, it just make it possible to choose a connection based on environment. The original problem was "Why the configuration that was set didn't actually work".